# The expression is not a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: distribution-theory

My problem is

> Show that $$u(\varphi)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!} \varphi^{(n)}(0)$$ doesn't define a distribution on $\mathbb{R}.$

I don't know where to start. I would like an answer.

thank you.

Comment: Hint: https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Borel_theorem

Answer (score -2):

Assuming $\varphi$ has a Taylor series expansion centered at $0$, which series converges at $1$, you seem to have written $\varphi(1)$ in a complicated way.

Comment: With $u_N= \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{(-1)^n\delta^{(n)}}{n!}$ then $\lim_{N \to \infty} u_N$ doesn't converge in the sense of distributions (ie. $\lim_{N \to \infty} <u_N,\varphi>$ doesn't converge for all $\varphi\in C^\infty_c$), but it does converge to $\delta(x-1)$ in the sense of analytic functionals (when restricting to analytic test functions), the key idea is that distributions are almost functions whereas analytic functionals are not ($u_N$ is supported at $0$ and $u_\infty$ is supported at $1$..)

Comment: @reuns : It seems odd that your answer has been posted as a comment.